# Mostrar layout android durante x segundos

Tags: android, android-layout

Boas, pretendo mostrar um layout durante 5 segundos. Já vi exemplos de como fazer isso assim que a aplicação abre, mas o que eu pretendo é mostrar um layout durante 5 segundos durante a execução da aplicação, ou seja, se um botão for pressionado mostra esse layout durante 5 segundos e depois continua a aplicação.

Alguma solução?

Comment: O que você mencionou quando a aplicação abre é chamado de Splash Screen e você pode utilizar recursos parecidos que são utilizados ao criar um Splash Screen, como, por exemplo, definir o tempo em que a tela ficará aberta, no seu caso 5 segundos.

Answer (score 0):

Dispara um relógio (com base na hora atual) assim no onClick do botão e quando tempo = 5 segundos, mata a activity com finish(); ou mata o layout.